# Navigation Property not lazy loaded EF6 Code First

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I've scoured the web and stack overflow for an answer for my problem but I've got no luck.

Basically I have a model that has 2 references of the same object and other objects as well. When I insert a record to the model, the properties are not loaded hence I tried the Context.Attach function to no luck. I also tried querying an existing record and the object still does not attach

Here is my Model

```
  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public Guid TripID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Range(1, 999999, ErrorMessage = "Total Distance can only be a positive number non-zero")]
    public double TotalDistance { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public double AmountDue { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public TripPaymentType PaymentType { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public TripStatus CurrentStatus { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TripTypeId")]
    public TripType TripType { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Guid TripTypeId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Guid CustomerID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CustomerID")]
    public UserInfo Customer { get; set; }
    public Guid? DriverID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DriverID")]
    public UserInfo Driver { get; set; }
```

Config for the single object multiple reference

```
             modelBuilder.Entity<TripHistory>()
            .HasRequired(th => th.Customer)
            .WithMany()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<TripHistory>()
            .HasOptional(th => th.Driver)
            .WithMany()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: why would related entries be loaded when you try to INSERT a new tuple? The Load() method might be what you are looking for, but after SaveChanges() you may expect a detached entity state.

Comment: Hi, it's because I have other transactions after saving the record. I've also edited the question to specify that I did try to query an existing record but the navigation property still would not be loaded

Comment: If you didn't dispose of the context after the save and just used the same context to do the retrieval you were probably getting the object you just inserted from the dbcontext cache.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference,

For some reason I had to force the loading of the objects even though lazy loading is enabled by using the .Include() method.